# Проблема c рекурсивным вводом в поле prompt

Tags: javascript

При запуске функции `power(number, exponent)` с параметрами `var number = defineNumber();`, когда в prompt не вводится значение, после его повторного ввода выводит 0. С чем это может быть связано?

```
function power(number, exponent) {
  var number = defineNumber();

  if (number === null) {
    return false;
  }

  var exponent = defineExponent();
  if (exponent === null) {
    return false;
  }

  var res = calc();

  function defineNumber(val) {
    var x = prompt("ВВЕДИТЕ ЛЮБОЕ ЧИСЛО", val || '');
    if (x === '') {
      alert('Вы не указали число');
      defineNumber(val);
    }
    return x;
  }

  function defineExponent(val) {
    var n = prompt("ВВЕДИТЕ ЖЕЛАЕМЫЙ ПОКАЗАТЕЛЬ СТЕПЕНИ", val || '');
    if (n === '') {
      alert('Вы не указали степень');
      defineExponent(val);
    }
    return n;
  }

  function calc() {
    var result;
    if (+exponent === 0) {
      result = 1; // если показатель степени  = 0
    }

    if (+exponent > 0) {

      result = +number; // если показатель степени  положительный
      for (var i = 1; i < +exponent; i++) {
        result *= +number
      };
    }

    if (+exponent < 0) {
      result = 1 / +number; // если показатель степени  отрицательный
      for (var i = +exponent; i < -1; i++) {
        result *= (1 / [+number])
      };
    }
    return result;
  }

  console.log(res);
  return res;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что значение запрошенное повторно никуда не возвращается:

```
if (x === '') {
  alert('Вы не указали число');
  defineNumber(val);
}
```

А возвращается первое введенное - пустая строка, которая как раз и приводится в 0.

Для решения достаточно вернуть это значение:

```
if (x === '') {
  alert('Вы не указали число');
  return defineNumber(val);
}
```

Comment: а что в данном случае делать? т.к. необходимо, что бы как раз при пустой строке выводилось сообщение alert.

Comment: @Shutenchik, можно сделать этому выражению `return`

Comment: добавила ``` if( x === '') {
        alert('Вы не указали число');
        defineNumber(val);
        return ;
      }``` выдает NaN

Comment: @Shutenchik, я обновил ответ с примером

Comment: Спасибо) работает))) Просто еще толком въехать не могу - т.к. это первая моя задача по JS - много чего не понятно пока.

Comment: @Grundy, ладно, два одинаковых ответа ни к чему, хотя я сразу привел код который решает проблему :-P Ваши шесть секунд победили))

Comment: @AlexKrass, да можно было и оставить, решение же дано, и даже другое :)